# How to Migration step for Long column in room database?

Tags: android-room

I have to add new column like Long, Integer and string in room database.
But migration not working?

```sql
ALTER TABLE 'followup_list' ADD COLUMN 'rmdTime' LONG NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```